# Gets null pointer execption error, complies though

Tags: java, stack, reverse

My program is to add word characters in a node, then pop out in reverse. It complies, but gives error at run-

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   ReverseLinkedList$Node.access$002(ReverseLinkedList.java:20)  at
>   ReverseLinkedList.push(ReverseLinkedList.java:44)     at
>   reverseWordTester.main(reverseWordTester.java:55)

Please help.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseLinkedList
{
   int counter = 0;
   private Node first = null;  
   private Node node = first;

   private class Node
   {
      private String item; // data in Node
      private Node next; // points to next Node in list.
   }

   public void push(String w1)
   {
      String word = w1;

      for (int i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
      {
         char c = word.charAt(i);
         String str = Character.toString(c);
         node.item = str;

         node.next = first;
         first = node;      

      } //end for

   } //end push method

   public String pop()
   {  
      String wordReverse = "";

      if (first ==null)
      {
         throw new EmptyCollectionException("Empty");
      }      

      while(first != null)
      {
         Node tempNode = first; //  first node is saved in tempNode

         wordReverse += tempNode;
         first = first.next;
         counter--;
      }

      return wordReverse;      


   } //end pop  


}    


My Main program :
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class reverseWordTester extends RuntimeException
{
   public static void main(String[] args)    
   {
      String inputSentence;
      String nextWord, getSentence;
      boolean more = true;


      // Creates scanner object
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      while (more == true)
      {
         // Prompts the user to type in a sentence
         System.out.println("Please type a sentence" );
         inputSentence = in.nextLine();

         if (inputSentence.equals("")|| inputSentence.equals(" "))
         {
            System.out.println("No sentence typed!");

         }
         else
         {

            // Displays the sentence typed by the user
            Scanner in1 = new Scanner(inputSentence);
            System.out.println("You typed the sentence: "+inputSentence);
            System.out.println("\nReversed word Sentence : ");


            while (in1.hasNext())
            {
               // Scans each word of the sentence
               nextWord = in1.next();

               // 
               ReverseLinkedList r1 = new ReverseLinkedList();

               // Sends the word to the constructor to reverse it

               r1.push(nextWord);

               // Pops the word in reverse order
               getSentence = r1.pop();

               // Displays the words of the sentence in reverse order
               System.out.print(getSentence);
               System.out.print(" ");


              }//end while
         }//end else

         // Checks if user wants to rerun the program
         Scanner ans = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("\n\nDo you want to try reversing word in sentence again? (y/n): ");
         String reply = ans.next();

         if (reply.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
         {
            System.out.println("Good Bye");
            more = false;
         }

      } //end while (more)
   }
}
```

Comment: Well it is not just a problem of null pointer there is more to this question than null pointer error. There is logic and coding errors. in the push and pop methods and the main.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you try to push and object `first` is `null` so you get a null pointer exception.

You have to add code to handle the first element being pushed similar to what you do for `pop()` when there are no elements left